# Easily hide error given by PS and show message

Tags: powershell, time, export-to-text

im currently finishing my PS script to get the time from a list of servers and export them to a .txt file. Thing is that servers with connection problems gives just a PS error. I want that servers with connection issues get logged also and by just a message i.e "Server *server name* not reachable". Thanks a lot for your help!

```
cls
$server = Get-Content srvtime_list.txt
Foreach ($item in $server)
{
 net time \\$item | find /I "Local time" >> srvtime_result.txt
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably rewrite your code a bit:

```
Get-Content srvtime_list.txt |
  ForEach-Object {
    $server = $_
    try {
      $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
      (net time \\$_ 2>$null) -match 'time'
    } catch { "Server $server not reachable" }
  } |
  Out-File -Encoding UTF8 srvtime_result.txt
```

Comment: This is what i was searching for. Its fast because it uses net time and also it outputs th results i needed. Thank you!
One correction i did in order to only have the time zone and the local time of the servers is the next:
`-match 'Local Time'`

Answer (score 1):

There are other/better ways to get the time (as others suggested) but to answer your question:

1. You can suppress errors by redirecting the error stream to null.
2. Check the $LASTEXITCODE variable, any result other than 0 means the command did not completed successfully.

   ```
   Get-Content srvtime_list.txt | Foreach-Object{

      net time \\$_ 2>$null | find /I "Current time" >> srvtime_result.txt

      if($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)
      {
          $result >> srvtime_result.txt
      }
      else
      {
       "Server '$_' not reachable" >> srvtime_result.txt
      }
   ```

   }

Comment: Dont know why but it doesn't work on the `net time` part. But thank you for the explanation on how to handle errors, it was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Test-Connection` cmdlet to verify that the remote system is reachable.

```
cls
$server = Get-Content srvtime_list.txt
Foreach ($item in $server)
{
 if (test-connection $item) {
     net time \\$item | find /I "Local time" >> srvtime_result.txt
    } else {
   "$item not reachable" | out-file errors.txt -append
}
}
```

But you can do this in pure Powershell, without resorting to `net time` - use WMI. This is untested as I don't have Windows handy at the moment, but it's at least 90% there.

```
cls
$server = Get-Content srvtime_list.txt
$ServerTimes = @();
Foreach ($item in $server)
{
 if (test-connection $item) {
     $ServerTimes += Get-WMIObject -computername $name win32_operatingsystem|select systemname,localdatetime 
    } else {
   "$item not reachable" | out-file errors.txt -append
}
}
$ServerTimes |Out-File srvtime_result.txt
```

Comment: It works, but WMI results slow for this procedure also it splits the results in two files. But its ok, thank you!

Comment: You can change what I wrote to create a single file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
Get-Content srvtime_list.txt | %{
   $a = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_ -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'
   if ($a) { "$_ $($a.ConvertToDateTime($a.LocalDateTime))"  } else { "Server $_ not reachable" }
} | Set-Content srvtime_result.txt
```

Comment: It works, but its a slow procedure also it doesn't shows the time zone.